# Does Nvidia rtx 3060 work in Matlab version 2022b for Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, gpu

I have plan to buy Nvidia rtx 3060 12 Gb. Does Nvidia rtx 3060 support in matlab 2022b to train CNN, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NVIDIA RTX 3060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3060-3060ti/) is part of the [Ampere architecture](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/ampere-architecture/), and looks like it is supported in R2021a and newer.

From [Does MATLAB support NVIDIA Ampere cards for GPU computation?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/592198-does-matlab-support-nvidia-ampere-cards-for-gpu-computation):

> For releases R2010b to R2020b support for Ampere will be via NVIDIA's
> forwards compatibility mode. Optimized device libraries must be
> compiled at runtime from an unoptimized version. Support can be
> limited and you might see errors and unexpected behaviour.
>
> Forward
> compatibility from CUDA version 10.0–10.2 (MATLAB versions R2019a,
> R2019b, R2020a and R2020b) to Ampere (compute capability 8.x) has only
> limited functionality
>
> Full Ampere built-in binary support within
> MATLAB is available from R2021a.
> For more details please see GPU
> Support by Release.